# is $\hat{\theta}$ unbiased

Tags: statistics

> consider a random sample of size n from a distribution with pdf $f(x;\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta}$  $0<x\leq \theta$ and zero otherwise. $0< \theta$

Now the first question was to find the MLE of $\hat{\theta}$ which I found to $X_{n:n}$ , now they want to find out if it is unbiased. My work so far:
$$
\begin{align}
E[\hat{\theta}] &=E[X_{n:n}] \\
&= E[n\frac{1}{\theta}[ln(\theta)]^{n-1}]
\end{align}
$$ 
now this is probably where i went wrong. isnt the cdf of $X_{n:n}$:
$$
nf(x)[F(x)]^{n-1}
$$
?

Comment: since $X_{(n)} < \theta$ it is clearly not unbiased.  No need to do any work.

Comment: I dont see that intuitively, could you give me a pointer?

Comment: every observation is in the range $(0, \theta)$, so the maximum is too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cdf of the maximum is given by $F(x)^n$. Thus, the pdf is $n f(x) F(x)^{n-1}$, In your case, we have for $0 < x \le \theta$:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\theta}$$

$$F(x) = \frac{x}{\theta}$$

Thus, the expected value of $\hat{\theta}$ is given by:

$$\int_0^{\theta}\frac{nx^{n-1}}{\theta^n}dx$$

That should hopefully help.

Comment: But I need the maximum right? $X_{n:n}$ denotes the maximum,, or not? Or should I not use the maximum of $X$ but the minimum of $\theta$? that sounds weird.

Comment: You are correct. I have fixed my answer.

Comment: I did my cdf by integrating $\frac{1}{\theta}$ but on $\theta$ and not on $X$. Thanks!